# Application crashes after returing to a previously invisible View in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-view

I have a ListView with a following problem: When ListView is initialised, everything is OK, when I scroll down to see new Views that were not visible it's still OK, but when I scroll up the see the View that used to be visible, but was then made invisible by scrolling (it was "pushed" off the screen as the user went through the ListView) the whole application crashed and I get a NullPointerException. Not sure why this happens, any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:
The problem seems to be with the convertView

ListView adapter:

```
public class EventListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
ArrayList<Venue> values;
Typeface aileronLight;

public EventListArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Venue> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.single_event_list_item);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    aileronLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Aileron-Light.otf");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return values.size() + 1;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = null;

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_event_list_item, null);
    }
    else{
        v = convertView;
    }

    if (position == values.size()) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.last_single_event_list_item, null);
        TextView noMoreResults = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.noMoreResults);
        Button changeSearch = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.changeSearchButton);
        Button exitApp = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.exitAppButton);
        noMoreResults.setTypeface(this.aileronLight);
        changeSearch.setTypeface(this.aileronLight);
        exitApp.setTypeface(this.aileronLight);
    } else {
        Venue currEvent = values.get(position);
        if (currEvent != null) {
            TextView singleItemTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.singleItemTitle);
            TextView singleItemLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.singleItemLocation);
            TextView singleItemDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.singleItemDate);
            singleItemTitle.setTypeface(aileronLight);
            singleItemLocation.setTypeface(aileronLight);
            singleItemDate.setTypeface(aileronLight);

            singleItemTitle.setText(currEvent.getName());
            singleItemDate.setText(currEvent.getDate());
            singleItemLocation.setText(currEvent.getLocation());
            AQuery aQuery = new AQuery(v);
            aQuery.id(R.id.singleItemImage).image(currEvent.getImageURL());
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.nightly.development.bussines.EventListArrayAdapter.getView(EventListArrayAdapter.java:72)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2285)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:725)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:664)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5424)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3374)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3774)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3583)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7714)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2224)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2151)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1596)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2502)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2099)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7894)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4124)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4003)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3499)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3499)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3632)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3499)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5799)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5770)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5935)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5881)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5954)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer
```

Comment: which one is line 72?

Comment: singleItemTitle.setTypeface(aileronLight). I tried removing that line and not setting Typeface but that is not the problem it seems. I think that for some reason android can't get TextView items from my View

Comment: can you debug/print if that singleItemTitle is null?

Comment: I checked now, it is null. I really don't understand why. I have all sorts of checks installed here. I check if View is null, I check is convertView is null. I don't get why it doesn't initialize

Comment: try to remove that V extra reference and inflate the convertView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with this part of your code:

```
if (position == values.size()) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.last_single_event_list_item, null);
}
```

So when you scroll to the last item, one of the created views will be reinflated and it will not contain anymore these text views:

```
    TextView singleItemTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.singleItemTitle);
    TextView singleItemLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.singleItemLocation);
    TextView singleItemDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.singleItemDate);
```

When you scroll up again the view which previously used by the last item is not NULL therefore it will not be inflated so it will hold the layout of the last item (thats why it returns null for those text views).

You can solve it in different ways:

1. Create the view for every item. It is an easy quick but i wouldnt recommend for a large number of items.

   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_event_list_item, null);
2. Or you can add one more condition to make sure that your view for the last item will be overwritten when handling other items:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = null;

```
if(convertView==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_event_list_item, null);
}
else{
    v = convertView;
}

if (position == values.size()) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.last_single_event_list_item, null);
    // rest of your code
} else {
    if(v.getId() != R.layout.single_event_list_item){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_event_list_item, null);
    }

    // rest of your code
}

return v;
```

}